# Is there an online Ukrainian-Ukrainian dictionary for native Ukrainian speakers?

Tags: resource-request, словники

Is there a recommended **online Ukrainian-Ukrainian dictionary** for native Ukrainian speakers, where I can write a word and get interpretation or definition in Ukrainian language? (Such as [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dictionary) for English for example).

Comment: I would consider approving another answer cause @follower clearly gave you much more links to work with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This type of dictionaries is called **тлумачний словник** ([explanatory dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanatory_dictionary)).

Try these ones, they are similar to Cambridge dictionary:

- http://sum.in.ua
- https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php
- [this Meta post](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8) contains a broad list of online sources including the explanatory dictionaries.

Comment: Both specified links ([http://sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua) and [https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php)) actually refer to the **same** dictionary — Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language in 11 volumes by Potebnia Institute of Linguistics (issued in 1970–1980), which is accessible through many different websites nowadays.

Answer (score 14):

Famous, official & the fullest, most people give credit to it:

*Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language* (DUL)

- in [**11 volumes**](http://sum.in.ua/), [1970—1980](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) by [Potebnia Institute of Linguistics](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potebnia_Institute_of_Linguistics);
- a newer one from [2010](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) in [**20 volumes**](//sum20ua.com) ([an alternative site](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry)) by [Ukrainian Lingua-Information Fund](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4) (where *as for now* only 10 volumes are outed) covers only *А—Обміль* letters.

---

The others:

- [sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua) as DUL-11 also includes small [Modern Online Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language](http://sum.in.ua/f) from 2013—2018.
- **[slovopedia.org.ua](http://slovopedia.org.ua/)** includes many Ukrainian—Ukrainian dictionaries;
- **[ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk)** has [DUL-11](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh), and [Signs of Ukrainian Ethnoculture](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury) by [Vitalij Žajvoronok](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%92%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

---

A site like [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php) is taking the source from DUL-11.

You can also see other dictionaries on our Meta [here](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/).